# IndexError: tuple index out of range, when trying to pass 2d array in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, tuples

I am trying to make some a program to explore the processing advantages using the library multiprocessing. However I receive an IndexError: tuple index out of range, when passing in multiprocessing.poolmap(, <2Darray>). My codes is as follows

I have tried to flatten the array, and it didn't work

````
import numpy as np 
import time 
import concurrent.futures 
import multiprocessing

def mean_py(array):
    start_time = time.time() 
    x = array.shape[1] 
    y = array.shape[2] 
    values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y): 
            values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:,i,j]))) 
    end_time = time.time() 
    hours, rem = divmod(end_time-start_time, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem,60) 
    print("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)))

    print(f"{'.'*80}")
    return values 

def generate_array():
    a = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    b = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    c = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    d = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    e = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    f = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    g = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    h = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)
    i = np.random.randn(1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000)

    arrays = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
    final_array = []
    for array in arrays:
        final_array.append(array)
        print(f"{array} added.")

    final_array = np.asarray(final_array)
    return final_array


start = time.time() 

final_array = generate_array()


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 2)

result = pool.map(mean_py, final_array)

#result = mean_py(final_array)

end = time.time() 

print(f'\nTime complete: {end-start:.2f}s\n')```



```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "implementation_v02.py", line 51, in <module>
    result = pool.map(mean_py, final_array)
  File "/home/roger/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 290, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/roger/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 683, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: tuple index out of range```
````

Comment: Is this all that your code is doing? `arr = np.random.randn(9,1000,1000).mean(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
result = pool.map(mean_py, [final_array, final_array])
```

You need to pass a list or a 1d array. It tries to map each element in the list or 1d array & "distribute" it to your pool.map function argument (mean_py). It doesn't know what to do with the 3 dimensions array you passed it... Should it takes each of the 9*1000*1000 element? Slice and pass only one dimension? Which one?

Comment: Thank you. It solved the IndexError, however I don't see any improvements in terms of processing speed. With this implementation ```result = mean_py(final_array)``` I am able to hit 19.0 seconds. With the multiprocessing.Pool implementation I am a bit above 20 seconds

Comment: @RogerAlmengor, you are comparing an apple to 2 apples. What Francky_V has proposed will run `mean_py(final_array)` twice and in _in parallel_. There should be no significant difference in speed compared to a single exeuction of `result = mean_py(final_array)` as you have written. To show the 2x speedup you expect, you need to run `result = mean_py(final_array)` twice _in serial_ (i.e. run the command twice in a row) and measure the overall time.

Comment: Yup - the point of the answer was to explain why the call to pool.map was wrong and how data can be sliced/organized so the code would run. As to how to divide that data in the first place, it would depend in your actual implementation/use case. As as brentertainer pointed out, best be careful when you think about performance in parallelel processing!

Comment: As a side note, the additional ~1 sec using the parallel version is normal. There is overhead cost in passing things to another process (the data, the function definition that has to be serialized somehow etc.). A good use of parallele processing must consider what to parallele, balancing those factors out....

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I need to rethink what kind of processing is more adequate for my use case. I want to process the mean along the Z axis in an array, and multiprocessing seems not to be the better option.